# How to use a factory constructor with null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

I'm trying to figure out if my updated code is the correct way to use a factory constructor with null safety.  I reviewed stackoverflow and the Dart.dev language tour to try to better understand factory constructors.  I have struggled to apply the concepts outlined to my code.  I'm new to Flutter, Dart and coding.  This is my first attempt at using a factory constructor so the primary issue is my lack of understanding and not any issues with the answers on stackoverflow or elsewhere.

After reading a lot I settled on the approach in the code below marked as Updated.  The errors are now all gone and my app is behaving as I want but my fear is throwing an error instead of returning null may not be a sound approach.  My approach just looks wrong to my beginner eyes.  My goal is for my code to work and to also understand why I am using whatever approach I am using so that I can apply that knowledge to future situations.  I can provide any additional code that may be needed to comment.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Original Code that throws an error

```
class Job {
  Job({required this.name, required this.ratePerHour});

  factory Job.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>? data) {
    if (data == null) {
      return null;
    }
    final String name = data['name'];
    final int ratePerHour = data['ratePerHour'];
    return Job(name: name, ratePerHour: ratePerHour);
  }

  final String name;
  final int ratePerHour;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'ratePerHour': ratePerHour,
    };
  }
}
```

Updated code that works

```
class Job {
  Job({required this.name, required this.ratePerHour});

  factory Job.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>? data) {
    if (data != null) {
      final String name = data['name'];
      final int ratePerHour = data['ratePerHour'];
      return Job(name: name, ratePerHour: ratePerHour);
    } else {
      throw ArgumentError('Data is null');
    }
  }

  final String name;
  final int ratePerHour;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'ratePerHour': ratePerHour,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: A factory constructor should behave like a normal constructor by always returning an instance of a object compatible with the class you are calling the constructor on (or throw an documented exception). If you want to be able to return a nullable instance, you should make a static method instead of factory constructor. So e.g. `static Job? fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>? data) {` which clearly communicates the possibility of `null`.

Comment: @julemand101 thanks very much.  Your answer is perfect.  Now I better understand some of the examples I read previously and I like my code much better than the way I attempted to fix the issue.  I don't see a way to vote for your answer.  It is exactly what I was looking for and didn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've pointed out several true and good facts, and I feel like that you're on the right way to implement this.

I also feel like there's no straight "right" answer to this question; I think this also connects to concepts as *clean code* and *clean architecture*, which are broader than Dart and Flutter themselves

You can either:

1. Throw and let the caller (upper layer) handle that problem;
2. Print some logs and return a zero-value to the caller (in your case, an "empty" object).

Case 1 is desirable if you don't want to handle cases like that one.

Case 2 is desirable if you can afford to return something weird like a `Job("job name",0)` and still be good.

It really depends on what you're building. By looking at your context, I'd probably go with option 1 and try/catch that in a middle layer (maybe you want to show your user "An error occured" whenever `data` is `null`)?

Nonetheless, you might need to refactor this feature in a way that allows you not to encounter these edge cases. There's a good chance [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) is your friend, here.

Comment: Thank you @venir.  I now have to think of the behavior I want with an error and then make a decision.  It's a confusing concept for someone like me.  Thanks for taking the time to respond as I was lost for hours trying to resolve.

Comment: I know case 2. might sound weird at first, but think about a `Stream` of data to be plotted in a time series-manner. In that case if something goes wrong it is better to set a `zero` value, print some logs and then move on to the next value. It would feel way weirder to throw an entire time series just because one single value had some parsing problems.

Comment: My inexperience makes a lot of things seem unusual but I trust the knowledge of others who have commented so I will be working through your two answers as well as one other answer today to try to think of the bigger picture of how I will apply the code now and in the future.  Can I explain the code to myself in the documentation that I write for the class?  That is the question I always ask. The 'context' of the code is that the Jobs class specifically is very minor but what I learn from the answers will help me write code for what is the broader project.

Answer (score 4):

Your own solution works fine however, I would check data before calling the factory.

```dart
factory Job.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
      return Job(name: data['name'], ratePerHour: data['ratePerHour']);
  }
```

But then again why not use data and call the regular constructor?

```dart
Job? job;
if (data != null) {
    job = Job(name: data['name'], ratePerHour: data['ratePerHour'])
}
```

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors

> Factory constructors
>
> Use the factory keyword when implementing a
> constructor that doesn’t always create a new instance of its class.
> For example, a factory constructor might return an instance from a
> cache, or it might return an instance of a subtype. Another use case
> for factory constructors is initializing a final variable using logic
> that can’t be handled in the initializer list.

Comment: thanks @Er1.  I will re-read the dart factory constructors tour information.  After seeing your answer it looks like I was adding unnecessary complexity to my code with the factory.  I was trying to account for the data from the server being returned as null and research made me believe the factory constructor was the best approach.